# How to make for-loop write specific line

Tags: python, for-loop, text-files

I have a text-file with a set of data. When writing to a new file, I'm using a for-loop but my for-loop writes every line for each line. For example: my data is

```
Hello
World
This
Is
The
Text
```

My intended output is for it to use xml tags to tag the data using strings. The output should look something like

```
<first>Hello</first>
<second>World</second>
<third>This</third>
""
""
<sixth>Text</sixth>
```

and so on. However with the loop I'm using my output looks like

```
<first>Hello</first>
<second>Hello</second>
<third>Hello</third>
<fourth>Hello</fourth>
<fifth>Hello</fifth>
<sixth>Hello</sixth>
<first>World</first>
<second>World</second>
<third>World</third>
<fourth>World</fourth>
<fifth>World</fifth>
<sixth>World</sixth>
""
""
```

and so on until it reaches the end. How do I fix this. My code is

```
def tagData(filename):
    original = open(filename, 'r')
    new = open('test2.txt', 'w')
    index = 0
    for line in original:
        if index%6 == 0:
            new.write('<first>'+str(line).strip('\n')+'</first>\n')
            index = index + 1
        if index%6 == 1:
            new.write('<second>'+str(line).strip('\n')+'</second>\n')
            index = index + 1
        if index%6 == 2:
            new.write('<third>'+str(line).strip('\n')+'</third>\n')
            index = index + 1
        if index%6 == 3:
            new.write('<fourth>'+str(line).strip('\n')+'</fourth>\n')
            index = index + 1
        if index%6 == 4:
            new.write('<fifth>'+str(line).strip('\n')+'</fifth>\n')
            index = index + 1
        if index%6 == 5:
            new.write('<sixth>'+str(line).strip('\n')+'</sixth>\n')
            index = index + 1
    original.close()
    new.close()
```

Comment: You need to use an `if - elif` structure.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're incrementing the index in each `if` statement.

Try this:

```
def tagData(filename):
    original = open(filename, 'r')
    new = open('test2.txt', 'w')
    index = 0
    for line in original:
        if index%6 == 0:
            new.write('<first>'+str(line).strip('\n')+'</first>\n')
        elif index%6 == 1:
            new.write('<second>'+str(line).strip('\n')+'</second>\n')
        elif index%6 == 2:
            new.write('<third>'+str(line).strip('\n')+'</third>\n')
        elif index%6 == 3:
            new.write('<fourth>'+str(line).strip('\n')+'</fourth>\n')
        elif index%6 == 4:
            new.write('<fifth>'+str(line).strip('\n')+'</fifth>\n')
        elif index%6 == 5:
            new.write('<sixth>'+str(line).strip('\n')+'</sixth>\n')
        index = index + 1
    original.close()
    new.close()
```

Comment: Well, that does *work* but it would've been better-off with an `if-elif` structure.

Comment: @AshishNitinPatil true, that's better because it won't evaluate 6 conditionals each time through the for loop!

Answer (score 7):

I'd write that as:

```
from itertools import cycle, izip

tags = ['first', 'second', 'third', 'fourth', 'fifth', 'sixth']
with open('input') as fin, open('output', 'w') as fout:
    for tag, line in izip(cycle(tags), fin):
        fout.write('<{0}>{1}</{0}>\n'.format(tag, line.strip()))
```

This avoids mucking about with the index and `if` logic...

Comment: my answer solves OP problem using OP logic, but this improves upon the logic with a more concise solution. +1

Answer (score 2):

A much better way to guarantee that `index` is correct is to just use [`enumerate`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate). That's what it's for:

```
def tagData(filename):
    original = open(filename, 'r')
    new = open('test2.txt', 'w')
    for index, line in enumerate(original):
        # etc.
```

Now you don't have to write `index += 1` anywhere, which means you can't possibly get it wrong, so your problem would never have arisen in the first place.

---

While we're at it, there are a few other ways to simplify this.

- While an `if`/`elif` chain is better than a bunch of independent `if`s, using a `dict` to map the index to a string is even better.
- If you use a `with` statement, you don't need those explicit `close` calls.
- It's much easier to read and write complex string formatting when you use the `format` method or the `%` operator instead of string concatenation.
- Since `line` is already a string, `str(line)` is unnecessary.

So:

```
tagnames = {0: 'first', 1: 'second', 2: 'third', 
            3: 'fourth', 4: 'fifth', 5: 'sixth'}

def tagData(filename):
    with open(filename, 'r') as original, open('test2.txt', 'w') as new:
        for index, line in enumerate(original):
            tagname = tagnames[index%6]
            new.write('<{}>{}</{}>\n'.format(tagname, line.strip('\n'), tagname))
```

But notice that in this case, the `dict` keys are just sequential numbers starting from 0. That won't be true in many programs, but it is here, so let's take advantage of it, and use a `list`:

```
tagnames = ['first', 'second', 'third', 'fourth', 'fifth', 'sixth']
# same code as above
```